# How to create Date Format (ymd) on Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I want to save the date as a timestamp or as a date format but theres no option for that type of string and if I make the date as a string/DateFormat(ymd)/or any other way it shows an error. The Code:

```dart
MyButton(
  label: "Create",
  onTap: () {
    _validateDate();
    ref.child('Time').push().set({
      'Title': _titleController.text,
      'Place': _subtitleController.text,
      'Date': _selectedDate, //ymd or yyyy/mm/dd or any other timestamp
      'Start Time': _startTime,
      'End Time': _endTime
    }).asStream();
    _titleController.clear();
  },
),
```

The `_selectedDate` format:

```dart
DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
```

Desired effect:

I want the date to be yyyy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, this will work for you. [intlDateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: When incorporating the format I get the following error: _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast) @okmsbun

Comment: ```final String startTime = "2021-09-02 00:00:00.000";
final DateTime? startDateTime = DateTime.tryParse(startTime);
if (startDateTime == null) return;
final String formattedStartTime = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startDateTime);
print("Start Time: $formattedStartTime");
```
You can use this to convert string to DateTime:
[DateTime tryParse static method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, there is no timestamp or datetime field type in FB RTDB. Also, you should not store dates as strings on databases as strings cannot be usefully processed as dates. On FB RTDB the recommended approach is to store dates as millisecondssince epoch, which is an integer.

Flutter/Dart provides methods to process this integer into DateTime variables that are then easily processed, displayed as strings, etc.

See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/DateTime-class.html